# Defining method_missing on Active record in rails 4 throws SystemStackError: stack level too deep on attributes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, method-missing

I recently upgraded my app to rails 4.0 and ruby 2.0
I'm having problems understanding why my `method_missing` definitions won't work. I'm pretty sure I'm not doing anything differently than I was before.

Specifically, I'm trying to create a method that lets an ActiveRecord object respond to a call to an object it `belongs_to` via a polymorphic relationship.

Here are my classes:

song.rb

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :events, :as => :eventable
end
```

event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :eventable, :polymorphic => true

    def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
       if meth.to_s ==  self.eventable_type
          self.eventable
       else
          super
       end
    end

end
```

I want to be able to call `event.song` when the eventable_type of event == 'Song'
The issue is on the `self.eventable_type`, which triggers a stack overflow.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though the `eventable_type` method isn't yet defined when `method_missing` triggers (some methods in Rails get dynamically defined through `method_missing` the first time you call them).

I'd try a different means of getting the value you want; perhaps `self.attributes["eventable_type"]` will work?

Comment: You, sir, are my personal hero for the day.